# check/log network utilization(shown in task manager) for remote systems

Tags: python, networking, lan, taskmanager

I have created a python script which runs a LanPort test on a group of systems for a specified number of hours.

Now for me the problem is that I need to log the Network Utilization % which can be seen by clicking on networkork tab of Task manager for all these systems. Is there any way of getting this done in python? If not , is there any other tool which allows me to open the task manager of remote systems such that I can monitor the performance from my management station.

Any kind of hep is really appreciated.

Thank You!!

Ashu

Answer (score 0):

Ashu, try taking a look at [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/)

From their page,

> **Summary**:
>   psutil is a module providing an interface for retrieving information on all running processes and system utilization (CPU, disk, memory, network) in a portable way by using Python, implementing many functionalities offered by command line tools"

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply!! I have already tried psutill but it gives me a bunch of values regarding network where as I need to log only the percentage of the network utilization. I really dont have an idea how can i calculate % from all those values.